# Animation Node Installation Error

Tags: animation, add-on, animation-nodes

Blender says I need to unistall prexisting animation addons before it can let me download the one by Jacques. Which one of these add-ons could it be referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation Nodes only wants you to remove other version of Animation Nodes currently installed. So just uninstall/remove any other version of Animation Nodes before installing it. So, leave those addons as is.

Comment: The only node I have is the node wrangler and that one cant be deleted. Blender only says it wants me to remove other versions of animation nodes when I install the Node Animation windows zip..maybe it's the zip file?

Comment: @JuanIgnacio What you need to do is go to the addons directory in your OS and remove any folder related to Animation Nodes. Blender may not recognize such folders as addons by AN will.

Comment: I went into the user preferences panel and into the Add-ons directory and looked through all those "Categories" and none have the option of being deleted. I've gone through them twice..

Comment: @JuanIgnacio As I said, if Blender can't see it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. You have to manually go to the *Addons Folder* in `/2.80/scripts/addons/` or where ever addons are stored in your system and delete any folder by the name Animation Nodes.

Comment: This [page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) describe the possible paths where addons can exist. Go over them one by one and remove the folders related to Animation Nodes. Makes sense?